# Environment variable in Vercel redirects

Tags: create-react-app, vercel

I want to deploy my create-react-app to Vercel.

I define my redirects in my `now.json` as follows:

```
{
   "redirects": [
      { "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "BACKEND_URL/$1", "statusCode": 200 }
   ]
}
```

The destination URL depends on the environment variable `BACKEND_URL`, which is defined in the Vercel dashboard.

I am trying to replace the environment variable in the redirects in the following build command:
`sed -i "s|BACKEND_URL|${BACKEND_URL}|g" now.json && yarn build`

But unfortunately `now.json` doesn't seem to be available at build time:

> 09:54:44.243   sed: can't read now.json: No such file or directory

How to enable dynamic redirects in Vercel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible since `now.json` is read to determine how to build so you can't dynamically generate it during a build.

Instead, consider using a framework like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) which provides a `next.config.js` that can read environment variables as defined in [RFC 9081](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9081).

```
npm install next@canary react react-dom
```

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    async redirects() {
      return [{
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/:path*`,
        permanent: false,
      }]
    }
  }
};
```

https://github.com/zeit/now/discussions/4351

Answer (score 1):

I think this actually is possible.
If you are using create-react-app then you just need to preface your env var name with `REACT_APP_`. See here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

I am currently doing this with a websocket URL env var. I have named it `REACT_APP_WS_URL` and here is how I use it.

I have 2 different `vercel` files in the project:

1. `vercel.staging.json` which has this section:

```
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "REACT_APP_WS_URL": "wss:staging.my-backend.com/socket"
    }
  }
```

2. `vercel.live.json` which has this section:

```
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "REACT_APP_WS_URL": "wss:my-backend.com/socket"
    }
  }
```

I deploy to them with either of these commands:

```
vercel deploy --prod -A vercel.staging.json
```

```
vercel deploy --prod -A vercel.live.json
```

and in my code I can access `process.env.REACT_APP_WS_URL` anywhere.

I have not tried doing this with the Vercel dashboard env vars but it might be worth trying your original approach except rename your env var to `REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL`.

Note: my deployment commands only work when I don't assign domains to the project. If I assign domains to a project, they are automatically used for ALL `--prod` deploys, no matter what is in my `alias` field in the json config file.